# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - Wifi not works properly

Tags: 18.04, wireless

I have a HP 240 G3 Notebook PC with Ubuntu 18.04 installed. The problem is that in a few hours or minutes after booting it disconnects from the wifi and dont recognize any network. When I reboot does the same. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a possible hardware problem. I would recommend using a separate wifi solution, such as a USB wifi adapter, to see if you run into the same problem with that device.

Comment: ok i will try it